# When are sequential seeks with small reads slower than reading a whole file?

Tags: c, performance, file-io, disk, seek

I've run into a situation where `lseek`'ing forward repeatedly through a 500MB file and reading a small chunk (300-500 bytes) between each seek appears to be slower than `read`'ing through the whole file from the beginning and ignoring the bytes I don't want. This appears to be true even when I only do 5-10 seeks (so when I only end up reading ~1% of the file). I'm a bit surprised by this -- why would seeking forward repeatedly, which should involve less work, be slower than reading which actually has to copy the data from kernel space to userspace?

Presumably on local disk when seeking the OS could even send a message to the drive to seek without sending any data back across the bus for even more savings. But I'm accessing a network mount, where I'd expect read to be much slower than seek (sending one packet saying to move N bytes ahead versus actually transferring data across the network).

Regardless of whether reading from local disk or a network filesystem, how could this happen? My only guess is the OS is prefetching a ton of data after each location I seek to. Is this something that can normally occur or does it likely indicate a bug in my code?

Comment: *"reading which actually has to copy the data from kernel space to userspace"*?

Comment: @netcoder: My understanding is that when you perform a read, the OS driver will put the bytes read off the disk/nic into a memory region in the kernel's address space, and to get that data into a normal program (a 'userspace' program) the kernel has to copy from from its internal buffer to one that the normal program is allowed to access. I've never done OS dev though so I could certainly be wrong about the details or maybe just not up to date on current methods...

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the difference will be a factor of the ratio of the seek count/data being read to the size of the entire file.

> But I'm accessing a network mount, where I'd expect read to be much slower than seek (sending one packet saying to move N bytes ahead versus actually transferring data across the network).

If there's rotational magnetic drives at the other end of the network, the effect will still be present and likely significantly compounded by the round trip time.  The network protocol may play a role too.  Even solid state drives may take some penalty.

I/O schedulers may reorder requests in order to minimize head movements (perhaps naively even for storage devices without a head).  A single bulk request might give you some greater efficiency across many layers.  The filesystems have an opportunity to interfere here somewhat.

> Regardless of whether reading from local disk or a network filesystem, how could this happen?

I wouldn't be quick to dismiss the effect of those layers -- do you have measurements which show the same behavior from a local disk?  It's much easier to draw conclusions without quite so much between you and the hardware.  Start with a raw device and bisect from there.

Have you considered using a memory map instead?  It's perfect for this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the filesystem, the specific `lseek` implementation make create some overhead.
For example, I believe when using NFS, `lseek` locks the kernel by calling `remote_llseek()`.